# Spring Boot 2 health actuator default mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I'm using Spring Boot 2 M3 actuators. By default, the health endpoint is mapped to `/application/health`.

- Is it possible to change this path to `/health`?

Comment: From Spring Boot Release 2.0.0RELEASE, /application is changed back to /actuator as was in Spring Boot 1.x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this documentation for Spring Boot 2.0.0,

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M4/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-customizing-management-server-context-path

the property is,

`management.context-path`

I think this should work but cannot verify it right now. 
`management.context-path=/`

Comment: This is correct for Spring Boot 1.x, but incorrect for Spring Boot 2.x. The property to use in that case is `management.endpoints.web.base-path`

Answer (score 19):

In your application.properties file add this to set the base path to '/'

```
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/
```

Path will now be '/health'

Edit:
Alternatively if you are using YAML use:

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      base-path: /
```

Answer (score 12):

FYI as of Spring Boot 2.0.0.RELEASE the default health endpoint is `/actuator/health`

Comment: Thanks! that helped me figure out why /health gives http 403.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is `endpoints.health.path`.

Update

Sorry, I understood like you want to change health to something else.

If you want change /application/health to /health, then you should use `endpoints.jmx.domain`. Or change path of your application to ROOT.

See

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html

Comment: I've been playing with `endpoints.jmx.domain` but I didn't make it. Do you know what is the value for that property to achieve my aim?